# Compare two snapshots of data and flag changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to write a query in SQL Server that compares two snapshots of data and flag changes. Column `load_datetime` is present to capture different snapshots from data.

Below are few conditions that need to apply,

1. I want to set it up so that I can easily pass a variable to compare any two snapshots
2. Return all columns and rows for the snapshot with the most recent LOAD_DATETIME
3. In the event a row (unique ID) exists in the prior snapshot but does not exists in the most recent snapshot, only then return the row from the prior snapshot and add a flag to indicate the row was removed
4. Add columns

   ```
    PRIOR_SNAPSHOT_LOAD_DATETIME
    Value =  LOAD_DATETIME of the prior snapshot

    SNAPSHOT_CHANGE_STATUS (Flag any changes between the two snapshots)

    NEW, REMOVED, VALUE CHANGES
   ```

   Could anyone pls suggest how I should go about it?

here is data,
[image]

Comment: Sample data and expected output would help

Comment: 1) What version of sql server do you have, 2) do you have the ability to make changes to the underlying table (namely,. turn it into a temporal table), 3) for 'value changes' would you instead accept two rows (one 'new' and the other 'old')?

Comment: *Could anyone pls suggest how I should go about it?* - Yes. You need to split your task into steps, then perform each separate step and ask individual question if you have any problem. Now your question is too broad and lacks data structures, sample data and desired output in text format

Comment: @astentx I have added sample data for clarity.

Comment: @pwilcox yes i have access to create a temp table. NO, i don't want two records in case they are matching. Have added sample data for clarity.

Comment: @Charlieface i have added sample data now.

Comment: Is there any unique column in your tables? Please, post the data as `insert` statements or at least as [tabular-formatted text](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/).

Comment: You may use window functions to calculate the number of versions and number of distinct versions, then decide. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=6d532c051849383fa1b15a28da16b14b)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234095/discussion-between-jinx-and-astentx).

Answer (score 1):

**You need a full join here:**

```sql
SELECT
    ISNULL(a.ID, b.ID) ID,
    ISNULL(a.Name, b.Name) Name,
    ISNULL(a.Amount, b.Amount) Amount,
    ISNULL(a.Region, b.Region) Region,
    a.Load_datetime,
    b.Load_datetime Prior_snapshot_datetime,
    CASE
      WHEN a.ID IS NULL
        THEN 'Removed'
      WHEN b.ID IS NULL
        THEN 'New'
      WHEN a.Load_datetime = b.Load_datetime
        THEN 'No change'
      ELSE 'Value Changes'
    END Status
FROM TableA a
FULL JOIN TableB b ON a.ID = b.ID;
```

You may want to change the condition `WHEN a.Load_datetime = b.Load_datetime` to reflect any other conditions you want.

Comment: If the `id` is unique

Comment: @astentx OP did say so in point 3